# setNavigationBarHidden makes whole view slide up/down

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES/NO animated:YES] makes the whole view slide up/down.Did anybody know how to solve this problem.It bothers me for a long time.Thanks very much!

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly you want and what exactly is happening.

Comment: @AkshayAgrawal What I want is when the navigationbar is hide,the whole view of viewcontroller won't slide up.It seems that no official API can solve this problem.

Comment: I think that you add the top constraint of the view controllers view with the navigation bar. So when it hides the view slides up and down respectively.

Comment: OK,it is a great idea,I would try it.Thank you so much.

Comment: kindly upvote if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `animated:NO`? Theoretically it shouldn't show the sliding if the animation if turned off.

Comment: I don't mean the slide animation,what bothers me is that while I  set the navigationbar and statusbar hide,the viewcontroller's view (`self.view`) of the navigationController's top viewcontroller will set the Y slide 64.f

Answer (score 0):

There are two option for hiding navigation bar or not.

1. [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES/NO];
2. [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES/NO animated:NO];

For your solution you can use first in which animation option is not there or you can use animated:NO. From my side its better to use first only.

Comment: I don't mean the slide animation,it's about the frame of `self.view`.It seems that at iOS7 and later,the view is layout at the bottom of navigation,when I hide the navigationbar and the statusbar,the view(`self.view`) will reset the origin of frame,so the subviews in view will all reset the origin